# How to change the path to user-created git-scripts

Tags: git

I wrote a script `git-foo`, so that now I can run `git foo` if `git-foo` can be found under `$PATH` or in `/usr/lib/git-core/`.

How can make `git` look for `git-foo` in `$HOME/scripts/git`, where all my other `git` scripts are, without having to append `$HOME/scripts/git` to `$PATH`?

Comment: Add `$HOME/scripts/git` to your `$PATH` in your `.profile` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not supported by git. But you could replace the `git` command with a custom wrapper script that adds that path to your `$PATH` before calling the real git.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an alias in your git config file which calls the binary. The alias definition can use the full path to the binary. Then the command will work for everyone who has the alias.